# Firestore: subscribe to document field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

in my Firestore I have users collection, every user have `notifications` field. How I can subscribe to this field values updates?

I tried to do this:

```
this.fireStore.collection('users').doc(`${uid}/notifications`)
   .valueChanges()
   .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

But I got an error:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users/IIhwHJDRnWcOFfHRv3ApXlovgEn1/notifications has 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't single out a specific field in a document for updates like this.  You must target a document, and any time any field in that document changes, you will get a callback.  If you think this is too much data to receive in a callback, you should split the data into multiple documents, and listen to only the documents whose fields you are interested in.

Comment: You mean, to store notifications for user as a separated collection, and associate it with a user by using the same key?

Comment: Sure, if that suits your case.  Or you can use a document in a subcollection organized under the user's document.